# UITableViewHeaderFooterView width issue on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have created a custom tableView header by subclassing UITableViewHeaderFooterView, its working fine on iOS 10 and later version but on iOS 9 the width is not adjusting with the tableView bounds. Steps I have used:- `New File > CocoaTouchClass > CustomHeader:UITableViewCell`. I have changed the `UITableViewCell` class to `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` manually.

2) Registered it in the viewDidLoad.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomHeader", bundle: nil),forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: CustomHeader.reuseIdentifier)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let customHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: CustomHeader.reuseIdentifier) as! CustomHeader 
return customHeader
}
```

**CustomHeader**

```
class CustomHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
class var reuseIdentifier: String{return String(describing: self)}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 244/255, blue: 245/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

**ViewController**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let customHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: CustomHeader.reuseIdentifier) as! CustomHeader 
return customHeader
}
```

**Result on iOS 9**
[image]

**Result on iOS 10 and later**
[image]

Comment: You are not setting header's rect.

Comment: I have already tried this ` customHeader.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50)` but still same result.

Comment: I don't know where you are setting it.

Comment: I was setting it in viewForHeaderInSection

Comment: Create a footer view with UIView (xib).

Comment: Actually I have used footerView as well, and it has the same problem. I tried to find out the width of header and tableview and its same, but customHeader.contentView.frame.width giving 6.94020030300593e-310

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**: Creating a footer view with `UIView` in code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 40.0)
    let footerView = UIView(frame: footerRect)
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 4.0, width: 200.0, height: 20.0))
    label.text = "Hello"
    footerView.addSubview(label)
    return footerView
}
```

**Approach 2**: Creating a footer view with an IBOutlet-connected `UIView` (.xib) object

a) Create a View file by choosing File > New > File.  Select View under User Interface.  Name a file.  For example, name FooterView.xib.

b) Create a `UIView` subclass file by choosing File > New > File.  Select Cocoa Touch Class under Source.  Name the file after selecting the UIView subclass.  For example, name FooterView.swift.

c) Select the `View` file.  And select `File's Owner` in the middle pane.  Then set the `UIView` subclass name (FooterView) as the class.  Open both the `View` file and the `UIView subclass` file.  Make an IBOutlet connection of the latter to the `Content View` of the former.

```
import UIKit

class FooterView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FooterView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        myLabel.text = "My footer"
    }
}
```

d) Add a `UIView` object to the view controller.  (See the picture below.)  Set the class name (FooterView).

[image]

e) Wire the footer view object to the view controller.

f) Prepare for table view's `viewForFooterInSection` delegate method.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // MARK: - Variables
    let list = ["George", "Nancy", "Jim"]

    // MARK: - IBOutlet
    @IBOutlet var footerView: FooterView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    // MARK: - IBAction

    // MARK: - Life cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    // MARK: - TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let footerRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 40.0)
        footerView.frame = footerRect
        return footerView
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]